# Styling placeholders for inputs that have a value?

Tags: html, css, placeholder

Trying out `::placeholder` pseudo-elements in forms instead of labels.

Wandering if I can change how a placeholder reacts when its input is typed in?

Ideally I'd have it remain visible like a label, but getting it to transition or something would be good too. [Here's a pen I'm playing with.](http://codepen.io/TheVelourFog/pen/PZJorJ)

Comment: y not using absolute positioning and putting 2 inputs one above the other?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want it to do? In your Codepen, it already "reacts" when the input is focused.

Comment: I'm looking for when the user has started typing in the input field.

Comment: You should use a label, the placeholder will vanish as soon as the user starts typing.